How can I assert JSON body hidden inside HTML tags with REST Assured?
I have response:
<html>
  <body>{"name":"test","value":"new","_id":"578641fec44c56220b15e5f9"}:</body>
</html>

I want to assert "name" using RestAssured body() method
I came up with this: .body("html.body", containsString("\"name\":\"test\"")).
Is there a way to do it more elegant using body()?

Please don't tag your titles, and make them a clear, specific question. See [ask].

What isn't elegant about the code you came up with? How is the elegance of answers to be judged?

I think it’s not good practice to use json as string. I want to be able to get field from json and compare it against its value  like in “equalTo()” method of hamcrest matchers
